# Zend Framework 2 get multiple rows

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2

I'm trying to get some rows from my database, where a field has a specific value.
I tried this code:

```
public function getJewelrybyCollection($collection)
{
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('collection' => $collection));
    $row = $rowset->current();
    if (!$row) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not find collection $collection");
    }
    return $row;
}
```

This is working, but is retrieving only one row, due to `$row = $rowset->current();`
I tried returning the `$rowset` var, with no good result.

I'm new to ZF2

Thank you

Comment: try a foreach on rowset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand what you're actually doing. Please refer back to the [official manual](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#zend-db) and work yourself through it again.

```
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(...);
```

The `$rowset` will be a [`Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/ResultSet/ResultSet.php). This `ResultSet` contains all `Rows` of your specified Query.

```
$row = $rowset->current()
```

With this line you're getting the first (the most current) `Row` of your `ResultSet`. Instead of checking for `if (!$row)` you could switch to `if(0 === $rowset->count())`, and then you'd only return the `$rowset`. As @Abadis pointed out, over the `ResultSet` you simply put a `foreach`-loop to gain access to every single of your `Rows`

Comment: Weird, I tried this last night, with no result. Tried it again, and now its working. I think it was a bit to late last night!  Thanks!!